# about rails3 routes match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a usercenter/users_controller,in this controller have code like belows

```
def login
end
def forgot
end
def reset_password
end
```

each method mapping a view login.html.erb, forgot.html.erb,reset_password.html.erb

now i want make a route for them at /usercenter/login
/usercenter/forgot
/usercenter/reset_password

how could i write route file ?

also i have a relevent question is is there some easy way for reduce write route mapping code because i have many controller method follow this rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is named routes. Check this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing